# Duplication following a path not rendering

Tags: rendering

I have two sets of object duplicated along a path (speed checkbox unchecked) and they are not rendering (though they used to do before) either in viewport or in real render.

[image: visible in solid mode]
[image: invisible in viewport rendering and in render result]
[image: visibility to camera not unchecked in object]

It's driving me crazy. What I've checked:
— Little camera in outliner selected
— Layers are selected in the render
— Visibility to camera not unchecked in object
— Material visible (works when not following a path)
And a few other techniques seen on the web.

Can someone please have a look at it?
[Here is the link to the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtcyugrryv1wd1h/hyperloop.blend?dl=0)

Thank you so so soooo much.

Comment: I looked over the file for an hour and didn't seem to be able to find anything. This seems to be a bug. I recommend you just recreate that curve from scratch. A lot of what are you are trying to do can be done using Animation Nodes more efficiently. Consider using it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make the duplicates real. Go to Object > Apply > Make Duplicates Real (...or Shift+Ctrl+A)

Comment: maybe showing an image of at least a small part of the scene rendered after doing that would show what happens better...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get lights to duplicate along a path and could never get them to light up after set to follow the path.. Making the duplicates real fixed it..

"You need to make the duplicates real. Go to Object > Apply > Make Duplicates Real (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)"